# Writing Complex SQL Queries Using Spring Specificaitons

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm having a complex SQL query which I want to execute in my Spring boot application. Following is a part of it's JPQL equivalent:

```
SELECT j FROM Job j WHERE
(   (?6 = 0L) OR 
    0L IN   (SELECT i12.filterFieldId FROM IjpPublishFilterFields i12 WHERE  i12.jobId = j.id AND    i12.fieldType LIKE 'GRADE') OR
    (?6 IN  (SELECT node.id FROM Grade node 
            INNER JOIN Grade parent ON  ((node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt) AND 
                                          parent.id IN (SELECT i1.filterFieldId FROM   IjpPublishFilterFields i1 WHERE  **j.id** = i1.jobId AND i1.fieldType LIKE 'GRADE'))
            WHERE   node.organizationId = ?5 AND         
                    node.isActive = true AND 
                    parent.isActive = true )))
```

Since there are multiple other conditions which require to form 'Where' clause dynamically, I believe `@Query` annotation is out of the window.

After a lot of research, still I'm unable to convert this where clause to Specification.
e.g., I can return whole `IjpPublishFilterFields` object but can't return just `i12.filterFieldId`.

How could I write the where clause using JPA Specification?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using `EnitityManager.createQuery()` and formed this equivalent JPQL using simple String concatenation. Still I believe, we should be able to form this `where` caluse using Spring data JPA `Specifications`. So, further hints are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about your query, so you should be able to translate this to something like `criteriaBuilder.or( criteriaBuilder.eq(param, 0L), criteriaBuilder.literal(0L).in(subquery1), param.in(subquery2) )` where `subquery1` and `subquery2` are constructed roughly like this: `Subquery<Long> subquery1 = criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class); Root<IjpPublishFilterFields> r = subquery1.from(IjpPublishFilterFields.class); subquery1.select(r.get("filterFieldId")); ...`